# Best practices to load very large images in a scroll view for zooming?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiimage, catiledlayer

I'm loading a very large image (8000x8000) into an `UIImageView` that's in a `UIScrollView`. This works but it consumes a lot of memory and takes a couple of seconds to load.

I've looked into a better approach and all the examples I have found are based on a 2010 WWDC example called PhotoScroller.  This example uses a custom UIView with CATiledLayer to break the large image into smaller tiles and draw them to the screen.

https://github.com/master-nevi/WWDC-2010/tree/master/PhotoScroller

Is there a more modern way to do this in iOS 13 or is this still the best approach?

Answer (score 0):

It is still the best approach. 8000x8000 is huge. You cannot load the whole image at once. CATiledLayer means you only need a few tiles loaded at a time — just the portion of the image that the user is looking at at the moment.

Comment: You might want to look at this section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_tiling Nothing significant has changed since I wrote that.

Comment: Ok, thank you. One thing I don't get about this approach is having to create tiles at different scales. This ends up using a lot of disk space.

Comment: You only need the different scales if you also want zooming.

Comment: And besides that's the whole point of the example. Disk space you've got plenty of! What you don't have is RAM memory.

Comment: Here's the zooming section of my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch20.html#_zooming_with_detail You can see the point is, if you don't use the extra tiles, you can lose detail as the user zooms in.